# Encoding and decoding in C

Tags: c, decode, encode

Hello I want to implement the below steps in my algorithm.

```
1) Take "a" from abcdefghi, add it at the end of an empty string -> a   
2) Take "bc" from bcdefghi, add it at the beginning of a -> bca
3) Take "def" from defghi, add it at the end of bad -> bcadef
4) Take the remaining characters "ghi" and add it at the beginning of bcadef -> ghibcadef
```

But I don't know how to write the above steps into a C programm. How can I copy a string at the beginning of an array?

This problem can be found at https://www.codingame.com/training/easy/disordered-first-contact.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Move the existing elements up the array to make room.  Don't omit moving up the NUL terminator.

Comment: "How can I copy a string at the beginning of an array?" --> research `memmove()` for general purpose copying.